# IDE-text selection with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

IDEs allow text searches like:

> search text: subnepas
>
> matched item: **sub**mit_**ne**w_**pas**sword

I think its convenient for users of a web app, for example `20ba` matching `202 Baker Street`.

How could I query a SQLAlchemy string column to do such substring matches efficiently? I am biased towards Postgres but I dont want to use ngrams or other full text indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for something like a [levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.

PostgreSQL has already a levenshtein/fuzzystrmatch, that you could use:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html

And here is an example how you could use it in SQLAlchemy:
http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@n@o@nomenklatura-HEAD@nomenklatura@model@matching.py/47/sqlalchemy.func.levenshtein

I personally didn't use this functionality till now. I always did the levenshtein comparison on the user side, but I had max 100 strings to compare and I had to load them all anyways, but on a larger scale it is probably better to let the DB do that.

Comment: The second URL is dead. Any chance of a newer, active URL?